# Travis-CI not being able to load tv4

Tags: npm, travis-ci

My project was passing on Travis till my last commit. After this commit, Travis says:

`Error: Cannot find module 'tv4'`  (at https://travis-ci.org/a85/Newman/builds/37216427#L141)

It has installed tv4@1.1.3 as part of the build (as seen at https://travis-ci.org/a85/Newman/builds/37216427#L40)

In version 1.1.3 of tv4, the name field in package.json is "tv4" (https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4/commit/4887d0f073951db681d23b9fde69ed7a9092fdea), so I guess it's not a case issue.

I've tried rebuilding a number of times, but it hasn't helped. Running `grunt test` locally works perfectly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue, but i managed to fix this when i changed **package.json** to the following:

```
{"main": "tv4.js"}
```

Instead of

```
{"main": "tv4.min.js"}
```

If you take a look at: 
https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4/issues/157

Comment: Thanks. How can I change package.json for the tv4 package? (Aside from uploading node-modules/tv4 as part of the repo, that is)

Comment: @Osiris In your folder, simply go to `node_modules/tv4/package.json` and make changes there. But that should have been fixed now with version 1.1.4, so a simple `npm update` should do the trick.

Comment: It was always working locally. But node_modules is ignored by git, so when I pushed to travis, the build there was failing.

Comment: Oh my bad, I misread the question. In this particular case, one option would've to fork that repository, and install your fork-ed version. (This would be a temporary fix though).